# Sn74hct04n - always pulls to Ground

Tags: led, digital-logic, inverter, not-gate

I have a very simple circuit in which I make use of an SN74HCT04N logic inverter to pull a line to GND when a button on 5V is pressed. You can see the circuit in my, unfortunately very bad, drawing.

[image]

So the idea is, when a button on a HIGH line is pressed, that should trigger the SN74HCT04N to pull the output to GND and thus closing the circuit of the LED.

Now, my issue is, that the LED is always slightly on. When the button is pressed, the circuit is actually closed and the LED lights up brighter. But, as said, the LEd is also on, albeit a bit dimmer, when the button is NOT pressed.

Can anyone explain to me, what I‘m doing wrong here?

Thank you very much in advance,

Christian

Comment: Add 10k resistor between gate input (6A) and GND.

Comment: why do you actually need the inverter? ... you can easily light the LED without it

Comment: This [page](https://inside.mines.edu/~coulston/courses/EENG383/lecture/lecture08.html) shows both configurations: Active low and active high.

Comment: Thanks all. As for why I need this circuit. The led is just a dropping replacement for an adafruit sound fx board. This board has input channels that are triggered when pulled to low

Comment: @siliconchris then use the button to pull low, and a resistor to pull up ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, the circuit driving the logic input is not correct.

The problem is that while the pushbutton is pushed, it sets the input voltage to high, but there is nothing to set the voltage low when pushbutton is not pushed.

So the voltage is indeterminate and will float at logic threshold level between high and low.

Add a resistor to keep logic input low while button is not pushed.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just one last question, why is a 10k resistor (as mentioned in above comment) needed between tha A and GND?

Comment: I think I just explained that if there is no resistor, the input will float at indeterminate voltage that can be high or low, but the resistor will keep it at definite level of 0V, unless you push the button.

Comment: Sure did you explain that without that resistor, the current will float, I just did not instantly understand that and th3n I was too quick to fire the comment. Somjust ignore my last comment. Now it makes sense